# Travis-CI - How is time limit counted for builds? (Sum of all jobs or time of longest one)?

Tags: timeout, continuous-integration, travis-ci, time-limiting

Let's say i have repo which for each push (build) starts 4 jobs (diffrent environment/compilers etc.).

There is time limit for builds - 50min. Is it counted as sum of times of all builds (like in left panel), or is it independant for each job?

Example: 4 builds, each taking 20minute - will it timeout becouse it will be counter as 80min or will it be ok and count as 20min (time of longest job)?

Answer (score 15):

The [Travis CI documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#Build-Timeouts) is pretty clear about this. A build consists of one or many jobs. The limit is enforced for each job:

> There is no timeout for a build; a build will run as long as all the jobs do as long as each job does not timeout.

For example, the current timeout for a job on travis-ci.org is 50 minutes (and at least one line printed to stdout/stderr per 10 minutes).