# Travis Build fails after 49 min even when logging output for all jobs every 1-2 min

Tags: ionic-framework, travis-ci, angularjs-e2e, saucelabs

I have a build for an Ionic project and its E2E testing with SauceLabs. The build is timing out after 49 min 17 sec(50 min). All of my jobs are running well and logging output frequently at least every 1-2 min. The timeout is happening consistently at 50 min.

My build goes meets all the requirements as mentioned [here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build#Build-Timeouts) to not suffer a time out. Also, there is no timeout for the build as mentioned in the docs. So the build shouldn't timeout as it is happening in the case. Any resolutions for this Issue?

Here are some of the logs:

- https://travis-ci.org/magician03/moodlemobile2/builds/241500777
- https://travis-ci.org/magician03/moodlemobile2/builds/241414546
- https://travis-ci.org/magician03/moodlemobile2/builds/241401570

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your build ends with this message:

> The job exceeded the maximum time limit for jobs, and has been
>   terminated.

It is the expected behaviour. Exists a limit of 50 minutes as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32128422/1009132) and [here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#Build-Timeouts):

> Build Timeouts #
>
> It is very common for test suites or build scripts to hang. Travis CI
>   has specific time limits for each job, and will stop the build and add
>   an error message to the build log in the following situations:
>
> - A job produces no log output for 10 minutes
> - **A job on travis-ci.org takes longer than 50 minutes**
> - A job running on OS X infrastructure takes longer than 50 minutes -  (applies to travis-ci.org or travis-ci.com)
> - A job on Linux infrastructure on travis-ci.com takes longer than 120 minutes
> - Some common reasons why builds might hang:
>
> Waiting for keyboard input or another kind of human interaction
>   Concurrency issues (deadlocks, livelocks and so on) Installation of
>   native extensions that take very long time to compile There is no
>   timeout for a build; a build will run as long as all the jobs do as
>   long as each job does not timeout.

Your build doesn't complete before for a specific issue in your build.

I would ask another question focused in your code and language `node_js`and no in this limit.

---

I develop native apps so I can not help on this topic but I found this [ticket](https://tracker.moodle.org/browse/MOBILE-1796):

It seems that they updated Node.js to 6.X, tested it using Travis-ci, it failed and currently they don't use Travis-ci, so I would ask directly to MoodleHQ in their forums.

> jleyva Juan Leyva added a comment - 03/Nov/16 6:05 PM Dani, can you
>   enable in your Travis account your moodlemobile2 repository so we can
>   see if Travis is working with the new dependencies? I already changed
>   the tracker fields so Travis is aware of the branch (but it requires
>   first you to enable you forked moodlemobile2 repo)
>
> jleyva Juan Leyva added a comment - 03/Nov/16 7:31 PM **Builds are
>   failing**: https://travis-ci.org/dpalou/moodlemobile2/builds/172896611
>   **Protractor or Jasmine or whatever is not working with this dependency**
>   **set**

---

You can also check [related issues](https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat/issues/168) and compare, [this configuration](https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat/blob/master/scripts/private/test-all.sh) works using:

```
node_modules/.bin/protractor e2e-tests/protractor.conf.js --directConnect
```

> in protractor-conf.js change chromeOnly to directConnect

Comment: Yes, I have noticed it lately. Now I guess I need to optimize my Travis build by dividing the build into various jobs